# how to display video per category in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

model video

```
protected $table = 'lokit_video';


protected $fillable = 
[
    'title',
    'cover_img',
    'trailer',
    'url',
    'order_',
    'active',
    'description',
    'lokit_category_id',
    'duration'
];
public function lokit_category(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

model category

```
protected $table = 'lokit_category';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

in controller

```
public function index(){
       $dataCategory = Category::all();
        $dataVideo = Video::all();
        $video = Video::where('lokit_category_id', $dataCategory)->get();
        dd($video);
        return View('bnpt.content.home',compact('dataCategory','dataVideo'));
    }
```

when I try the code above what happens with the code is null, how to fix it?

Comment: You want to display all the videos for a certain category?

Comment: Yes, like that, but I'm confused to write the code

Comment: `You want to display all the videos for a certain category? ` You said yes to this. So you want to get the videos of which category, please mention the category

Comment: i want to display video for a certain lokit_category_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the videos related to all the categories, you should develop the relationship.

In `Category` Model:

```
    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Video::class);
    }
```

In the controller method:

```
$dataCategory = Category::all();
return View('bnpt.content.home',compact('dataCategory'));
```

In the view file:

```
<ul>
@foreach($dataCategory as $category)
    <li><span>{{$category->name}}</span>
        <ul>
           @foreach($category->videos as $video)
                   <li><span>{{$video->name}}</span></li>
           @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**PROBLEM**]In your code you have

```
$dataCategory = Category::all();

$video = Video::where('lokit_category_id', $dataCategory)->get();
```

`$dataCategory` is a **collection of the model instances** of all the entries in your **lokit_category** table.

[**SOLUTION**]
You can't compare a `collection` with a field that expects an `id` in your case in the where statement.

`lokit_category_id` should be **compared with the id of a category**.

If you have the **lokit_category_id**

```
$videos = Video::where('lokit_category_id', $lokit_category_id)->get();
dd($videos);
```

If you have the **name** of the lokit_category, get the id using that name and then make the query.

```
// Get the category for which you want to get all the videos.
$categoryName = 'CATGEORY NAME';

$category = Category::where('name', $categoryName)->first();

$videos = Video::where('lokit_category_id', $category->id)->get();
dd($videos);
```

[**IF YOU WANT VIDEOS WITH RESPECT TO A CATEGORY**]

In your Category Model

```
public function videos(){
   return $this->hasMany(App\Video::class, 'lokit_catgeory_id', 'id');
}
```

Controller

Use **eager loading** as it will help in reducing the number of queries.

```
$categories = Category::with('videos')->get();

foreach($categories as $category){
    // You can access the videos for the category using the videos relation.
    $category->videos;
}
```

Comment: when i debug dd ($ category) the contents are null

Comment: Did you assign $categoryName with the name of the category for which you want to get the videos?  As your post's title states you wanted to get the videos for a given category, now seeing your category model, I assumed you would know the name of the category for which you want the videos. So assign `$categoryName` to the categoryName for which you need the videos.

Comment: You could get the categoryName as a parameter to the function in the controller, that way  you could pass the categoryName and get the videos for that category.